# What is spring boot's databse initialization behaviour with hibernate JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using the book Spring in Action 5th edition to learn spring. It had told me to write some jdbc code which was facilitated by H2 database and schema.sql data.sql. It worked. Then it told me to switch to JPA by including spring-boot-starter-data-jpa package in pom.xml. However, I found schema.sql and data.sql were not executed because the database schema is different from what I wrote in schema.sql, and there was no data inside.

I got the impression that hibernate creates tables for me by looking into classes which was annotated with @Entity. It did not work for me. I did some googling and added a property setting to turn the create table action off. however, the schema is different from what the book wrote in schema.sql in previous section. For example, there is a java object field called "createdAt" and was defined in schema.sql as "createdAt" ( the book wrote it this way ), but hibernate expected "created_at".

Answer (score 2):

We have to change the naming strategy to prevent `createdAt` as `created_at`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

*Note: spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy is not a supported property for Spring JPA implementation using Hibernate 5.*

For Spring Boot 1.4.x

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```